# Scheme list (RECURSION)

Tags: list, recursion, scheme

I have a list of lists [(1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)] which is for a matrix.
I am looking for how to get the diagonal( which should be (1 5 9).
My code provides me with an error "OPERATOR IS NOT A PROCEDURE". i dont know exactly what i did wrong in this. Help would be appreciated.THE CODE IS BELOW.

```
(define (diagonal lst)
(if(null? lst)
(0)
((cons (list-ref (reverse (car lst)) (- (length lst) 1)) (diagonal (cdr lst))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

`(0)` -> you cannot evaluate the procedure `0`, because it's not a procedure. Drop the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

The diagonal of

```
a b c d 
e f g h
c d e f
g h i j
```

consists of the a (the first element of the first list)
followed by the diagonal of

```
  f g h
  d e f
  h i j
```

The matrix above consists of the rows of the original matrix with the first row omitted and the first column removed.

```
(define (diagonal m)
   (if (empty-matrix? m) 
       '()
       (cons (first (first m))
             (diagonal (remove-first-column (remove-first-row m))))))

 (define (remove-first-column m)
    ...fill-in...)

 (define (remove-first-row m)
    ...fill-in...)
```